# Custom control properties don't appear when accessing via form.Control(ItemIndex).Custom property

Tags: .net, vb.net

I just made a custom button control using vb.net 2010 and provided some custom properties in that control.

Now everything looks fine, but after adding that custom control on a new form and trying to access my custom control properties i cannot see the custom properties (`CustomProperty1,CustomProperty2 and CustomProperty3`)
I'm using that code to access :

```
Form1.Controls(MyCustomControlIndex).CustomProperty1
```

Here I can't see `CustomeProperty1` in the intellisence menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's normal: `Form1.Controls(MyCustomControlIndex)` returns a Control object (as you can see from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/333f9hk4%28v=vs.100%29)), so it does not have user defined properties.
You should cast it to the type of your user-control and then every property should be shown with IntelliSense.